# TensorFlow MobilenetV2 Object Detection web model format export problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mobilenet, tensorflowjs-converter

I want to fine tune MobileNet v2 and export to json + binary format. Unfortunatelly, there is a problem with exporting. I'll show it on the most basic example - plain MobileNet v2 without fine tuning:

1. Download and extract [SSD MobileNet v2](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz).
2. Using tensorflowjs_converter I can export saved_model/ to web format. It works as expected:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --control_flow_v2=True --input_format=tf_saved_model --metadata= --saved_model_tags=serve --signature_name=serving_default --strip_debug_ops=True --weight_shard_size_bytes=4194304 saved_model/ web_model/
```

3. It is possible to import model in browser. Just load tfjs:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
```

And load model and test it on example picture:

```
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel("/web_model/model.json");
await model.executeAsync(tf.expandDims(tf.browser.fromPixels(document.getElementById('cat')), 0))
```

Returns some data.
**This works fine.**

Problem occurs when I try to export web model from checkpoint (before or after fine-tuning). Lets take checkpoint before fine tuning. First, export checkpoint (from MobileNet v2 directory) to inference graph:

```
python models/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py     --trained_checkpoint_dir="checkpoint"     --output_directory="saved_model"     --pipeline_config_path="pipeline.config"
```

Then use same command to export:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --control_flow_v2=True --input_format=tf_saved_model --metadata= --saved_model_tags=serve --signature_name=serving_default --strip_debug_ops=True --weight_shard_size_bytes=4194304 saved_model/ web_model/
```

After importing model in web (just like step 3):
[image: error in broweser]
There is an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backend')
```

I noticed that in model.json there are some addiotional functions:

Working model:
[image]
Not working model:
[image]

*modelTopology* is diffrent. Can someone explain me why this is happening? It looks like diffrent configuration after using inference graph exporter.

For fine tuning it is possible to use code from [this example colab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tflite.ipynb). Checkpoint generated with this code returns same
*undefined backend* error.

Tested with many versions of TensorFLow and TensofFlowJS, currently using tensorflow==2.4.1, tensorflowjs==3.20